# Explanation SIP technology

Tags: sip, android

I have a question regarding SIP. Well, whether on a regular VPS I am capable to put a workable server? I wanted to play with voice communication on the Android platform, I read that it supports the SIP API, which is why I'm asking. If, however, do not have the physical capabilities to do something like that, I wanted to find out if exists alternative to SIP, so I could communicate a voice on a cell phone.

I go here from StackOverflow, they recommend asking question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about 4 questions.

1. A regular VPS should be able to run an asterisk server (though not for hundreds of people) or a kamailio server, if you're looking to do SIP routing instead.
2. Android has SIP capable clients, but it's designed to run on fairly low powered hardware, so I don't know how good a job it would do with multiple RTP streams.
3. SIP isn't voice. SIP is the Session Initialization Protocol. It does of all of the setup, teardown and modification of the calls, but the actual communication is done in another protocol.
4. There are alternatives to SIP, H.323, IAX2 even XMPP and Vsee..

Comment: Adding to 4 - the voice is done using RTP.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly. beware though that sip requires near realtime processing. If you vps provider is overbooking the hardware, your connection quality might vary.

I would also have a look at http://asterisk.org/. SIP is not very good at NAT-Traversal, typically encountered in mobile scenarios. Clients should be available for your $favorite mobile platform.

Comment: would dealing with NAT be a use case for running kamailio?